# Big tangent bundle

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles, fano-varieties, toric-varieties, homogeneous-spaces

Let $X$ be a nonsingular complex algebraic variety whose tangent bundle is $T_X$. I use Lazarsfeld's book for the definition of a big vector bundle. A line bundle $L$ is big if it has Itaka dimension dim$X$.
A vector bundle $E$ is big if the line bundle $O_{P(E)}(1)$ is big on the projective bundle $P(E)$ of one dimensional quotients of $E$.

Questions:

1. Does there exist a Fano manifold $X$ whose $T_X$ isn't big?
2. Is it true that $T_X$ is big for any nonsingular toric variety $X$?
3. How about for (partial) flag varieties or more generally homogeneous spaces G/P?

Comment: I think it would be a very good thing if you included the definition of "big" rather than expecting people to get hold of a particular book and look it up.

Comment: Just to clarify: I think that bigness of $T_X$ refers to the line bundle $O(1)$ being big on $\mathbb{P}(T_X)$. As usual, a line bundle $L^m$ is big if $\dim H^0(mL)$ grows asymtotically as $m^{\dim X}$ for $m$ large.

Comment: Also, I feel that the downvote is a bit harsh. I think it makes sense to ask this question and it it interesting.

Comment: I agree with J.C Ottem. This seems to have gotten two downvotes now. Is this just because the definition of big is missing?

Comment: Thanks J.C. Ottem for clarify the definition.
This is the definition I use. Sorry for being lazy.

Comment: I'm interested to these questions: does someone know the answers?